# Django form query

Tags: django-forms

I saw this piece of code and have few questions..If anyone could explain that would be really helpful.

views.py

```
def search_page(request):
    pdb.set_trace()
    form = SearchForm()
    bookmarks = []  
    show_results = False
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        show_results = True
        query = request.GET['query'].strip()
        if query:
           form = SearchForm({'query': query})
           bookmarks = Bookmark.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    variables = RequestContext(request,{'form': form,
                                       'bookmarks': bookmarks,
                       'show_results': show_results,
                       'show_tags': True,
                       'show_user': True})

    return render_t7tr o_response('search.html', variables)
```

form.py
    class SearchForm(forms.Form):
        query = forms.CharField(label=u'Enter a keyword to search for', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':32}))

How do the below line of code work?

If 'query' in request.GET

how the 'query' string is in the request.Get?..When I debugged the dictionary contains the value contains the search value I have given.

THe code works fine but I want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Containment testing on [mappings](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) checks the keys.

> ```
> key in d
> ```
>
> > Return `True` if *d* has a key *key*, else `False`.

**EDIT:**

Django parses the query string and populates `request.GET` from it.

Comment: how does the dictionary contains the KEY-'query'..The VALUE that I gave is 'GOOGLE'(Example)..